# CSS Table Resizing inside a DIV

Tags: html, css

I have a table which i am having trouble with. I would like to have both tables side by side in the Div both of equal widths. I have tried to manually set the widths ect but with no success any help at all with this would be great.

It looks like this currently
[image]

Html

```
<div class = "CoresAreaDiv"> 


<label class="CoresLabel">CoreShop</label>  

<table  class="CoreShopTable"  >

<tr>
<th>
L1
</th>

<td>@ViewData["L1"]</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<th>L2</th>
<td>@ViewData["L2"]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>L3</th>
<td>@ViewData["L3"]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>L4</th>
<td>@ViewData["L4"]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>L5</th>
<td>@ViewData["L5"]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>L6</th>
<td>@ViewData["L6"]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>L7</th>
<td>@ViewData["L7"]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>L8</th>
<td>@ViewData["L8"]</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table class="CoreShopTable2">

<tr>
<th>L9</th>
<td>@ViewData["L9"]</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>L10</th>
<td>@ViewData["L10"]</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>L11</th>
<td>@ViewData["L11"]</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>L12</th>
<td>@ViewData["L12"]</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>L13</th>
<td>@ViewData["L13"]</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>L14</th>
<td>@ViewData["L14"]</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>L15</th>
<td>@ViewData["L15"]</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>L18</th>
<td>@ViewData["L18"]</td>
</tr>




</table>

</div>
```

The CSS code for the following is

```
    .CoresAreaDiv 
{

 width:50%;

}


}
table.CoreShopTable
{
    text-align: left;
    margin: 45px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode" , "Lucida Grande" , Sans-Serif;
    width: 20%;;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}


table.CoreShopTable th
{
    width: 2%;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 8px;
    background: #b9c9fe url('table-images/gradhead.png') repeat-x;
    border-top: 2px solid #d3ddff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #039;
    font-size: larger;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-align: center;
}


table.CoreShopTable td
{
    padding: 8px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #669;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    background: #e8edff url('table-images/gradback.png') repeat-x;
    font-size: larger;
    text-align: center;
    width: 2%;
}

table.CoreShopTable td:hover
{
    background: #d0dafd url(C:\Users\pbrady\Desktop\Code\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\Images\gradhover.png);
    color: #339;
}


table.CoreShopTable2
{
    text-align: left;
    margin: 45px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode" , "Lucida Grande" , Sans-Serif;
    width: 50px;
    float: right;
    right: -50px;
    top: -357px;
    position: relative;

}

table.CoreShopTable2 th
{
    width: 20%;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 8px;
    background: #b9c9fe url('table-images/gradhead.png') repeat-x;
    border-top: 2px solid #d3ddff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #039;
    font-size: larger;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-align: center;
}


table.CoreShopTable2 td
{
    padding: 8px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #669;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    background: #e8edff url('table-images/gradback.png') repeat-x;
    font-size: larger;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Please show the HTML as well...

Comment: you need to look at your widths - some tds are set to 2% and your second table is set to 50px - sort these out and it should work properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/npvK5/

took me a while to figure-out what your problem was.

1. you had an extra closing braclet `}` in your css. causing the stylesheet not to load correctly.
2. your containing div was too small for 2 tables [on the fiddle page] (they need to be at least large as their content), so I dropped the `width: 50%;`. but on a regular page, you should have enough space, so you can bring it back.
3. you had `position: relative;` all over the place, and unnecessary `top` & `right` declarations. with some `margin` to the tables that ruined everything. all of that is gone in the wind.
4. I've dropped the `width` and `padding` declaration for `th` & `td` (some of them were `2%` and some `20%`, other were `50px`, dude.. its a mess, bring them back as you need them. they shoud not affect the layout.
5. I've add an `<br/>` to seperate the tables from the label.
6. i've dropped all default `margin` & `padding` to gain use of all available space (using `*` selector).

while I was there, I took the liberty to fix some of your CSS as well, notice how my fiddle is clearer and easier.
I've dropped some of the declaration, because they are default. remmember - less is more.

so, in conclution:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="CoresAreaDiv">
    <label class="CoresLabel">CoreShop</label>
    <br/>
    <table class="CoreShopTable">
        <tr>
            <th>L1</th>
            <td>@ViewData["L1"]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>L2</th>
            <td>@ViewData["L2"]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>L3</th>
            <td>@ViewData["L3"]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>L4</th>
            <td>@ViewData["L4"]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>L5</th>
            <td>@ViewData["L5"]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>L6</th>
            <td>@ViewData["L6"]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>L7</th>
            <td>@ViewData["L7"]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>L8</th>
            <td>@ViewData["L8"]</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="CoreShopTable">
        <tr>
            <th>L9</th>
            <td>@ViewData["L9"]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>L10</th>
            <td>@ViewData["L10"]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>L11</th>
            <td>@ViewData["L11"]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>L12</th>
            <td>@ViewData["L12"]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>L13</th>
            <td>@ViewData["L13"]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>L14</th>
            <td>@ViewData["L14"]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>L15</th>
            <td>@ViewData["L15"]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>L18</th>
            <td>@ViewData["L18"]</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
*
{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
table.CoreShopTable
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
table.CoreShopTable th {
    background: #b9c9fe url('table-images/gradhead.png') repeat-x;
    border-top: 2px solid #d3ddff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #039;
    font-size: larger;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
table.CoreShopTable td
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #669;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    background: #e8edff url('table-images/gradback.png') repeat-x;
    font-size: larger;
    text-align: center;
}

table.CoreShopTable td:hover {
    background: #d0dafd url(C:\Users\pbrady\Desktop\Code\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\Images\gradhover.png);
    color: #339;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works..

```
<div width="100%">
<table width="48%">
//your stuff
</table>
<table width="48%">
//your stuff
</table>
</div>
```

table width can be maximum upto 50%..
If it doesnot work for you.Then use float:left;

Comment: Have used both but sill no joy

Comment: thats because you had another issues in your CSS. as a generality, his solution is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the div, it's sparating the tables, I don't see why you don't just have in in another row in that table, and not just the same table but I'm sure you have you're reasons,

```
.CoresAreaDiv {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

or....

you could just remove the left border of the second table:

```
.CoreShopTable2 tr {
border-left: none;
margin-left: 0; /* to make sure there is still no awkward space */
}
```

or keep the border, whichever